# Limit Javascript COPY Button to a single DIV/Text Area

Tags: javascript, html, button, copy, textarea

I am creating a webpage with a various number of scripts in text fields that my team can just click a button to copy whats in the text field so they can paste it into a device to run the script. However, since javascript runs the last script in the HTML code, the buttons all do what the last script says. I need to limit them to the divs the buttons are in. I have added a screenshot to show what it looks like but I am hoping there is a way this can be done.

I have given each of the text areas a name and the script specifically states to call that ID but when I click the button - it will only copy the field of the 3rd DIV

[Screenshot of what the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCtzL.png)

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <b>IAD Config - 2400s ONLY</b>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
         <textarea id="iad" rows="5">
          IAD Config
         </textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
         <button id="iadcopy">Copy</button>
          <script>
             var input  = document.getElementById("iad");
             var button = document.getElementById("iadcopy");

             button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 input.select();
                 document.execCommand("copy");
             });
          </script>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <b>ACL</b>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
         <textarea id="acl" rows="5">
          ACL script
         </textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
         <button id="aclcopy">Copy</button>
          <script>
             var input  = document.getElementById("acl");
             var button = document.getElementById("aclcopy");

             button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 input.select();
                 document.execCommand("copy");
             });
          </script>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <b>NOC Username</b>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
         <textarea id="noc" rows="5">
          ACL script
         </textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
         <button id="noccopy">Copy</button>
          <script>
             var input  = document.getElementById("noc");
             var button = document.getElementById("noccopy");

             button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 input.select();
                 document.execCommand("copy");
             });
          </script>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were overwriting what `input` was with your inline javascript (which is usually a bad idea in general).  By making them unique variable names, it copies the correct one.  It would probably be a good idea to refactor this in a more programatic way, using jQuery to select the closest textarea to copy or give each pair the same class name in order to scope the targeting correctly.

Note - because you immediately add an event listener after declaring(and redeclaring `button`), while your approach isn't the best, it doesn't suffer from the same problems as redeclaring `input`.

```html
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <b>IAD Config - 2400s ONLY</b>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
         <textarea id="iad" rows="5">
          IAD Config
         </textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
         <button id="iadcopy">Copy</button>
          <script>
             var input1  = document.getElementById("iad");
             var button = document.getElementById("iadcopy");

             button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 input1.select();
                 document.execCommand("copy");
             });
          </script>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <b>ACL</b>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
         <textarea id="acl" rows="5">
          ACL script
         </textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
         <button id="aclcopy">Copy</button>
          <script>
             var input2  = document.getElementById("acl");
             var button = document.getElementById("aclcopy");

             button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 input2.select();
                 document.execCommand("copy");
             });
          </script>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <b>NOC Username</b>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
         <textarea id="noc" rows="5">
          ACL script
         </textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
         <button id="noccopy">Copy</button>
          <script>
             var input  = document.getElementById("noc");
             var button = document.getElementById("noccopy");

             button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 input.select();
                 document.execCommand("copy");
             });
          </script>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand this is not a typical or best practice but this is what hung me up.